# Apache 2 mod_rewrite - How to read POST parameters?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http

I would like to use mod_rewrite to read parameters sent in POST requests. I need to check the value and process the request.

Answer (score 5):

`Mod_rewrite` will not work on POST variables.

You would need to use [`mod_security`](http://www.modsecurity.org/) to examine, and possibly [run a url-rewriting script](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/05-actions.html), on any POST variables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it's possible.

`mod_rewrite` can only work on the contents of the initial request line, headers and environment variables. Whereas the parameters of a POST request are found within the request body.

Comment: Is there a module I can use to access the request body ?

Comment: @Julien: normally you would use a CGI script for that. Or some sort of web application (mod_python, mod_perl, Java servlet, PHP page, etc.)